# Transforming array with numbers and operators

Tags: javascript, arrays

I manage to have this arraylist :

```
["1","2","+","2","1","2"]
```

But I would like to sort it in order to have

```
["12","+","212"]
```

But I can't figure out how to this.

UPDATE :

```
let al = ["1","2","+","2","1","2"];
for(let i=0;i.length;i++) {
  if(al[i] != "+" && al[i+1]) {
    al[i] += al[i+1];
   }
}
```

I think I could use a while loop

Comment: Could you ahow the attempt to solve your problem?

Comment: I don't see any sorting here? Your second array is a transformed array rather than sorted.

Comment: Your loop is running forever?

Comment: @MohammadUsman I believe it is a figure of speech. Kind of like the idiom "sort it out" e.g. steps to take in order to address an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the easiest way. Just write a reducer to append tokens to a stack.

```js
const OPERATORS = /[+\-\*\/]/;
function toExpression(tokens) {
  return tokens.reduce((result, token) => {
    if (OPERATORS.test(token)) {
      result.push(token, '');
    } else {
      result[result.length - 1] += token;
    }
    return result;
  }, ['']);
}

let arr1 = ["1", "2", "+", "2", "1", "2"];
let arr2 = toExpression(arr1);

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Combine join and split by regex:

```js
    
    var a = ["1","2","+","2","1","2"];
    a = a.join('').split(/([x^+-])/);

    console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could join and split by word boundary position, without mention the operators.

```js
var array = ["1", "2", "+", "2", "1", "2"],
    result = array.join('').split(/\b/);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go over the array and join everytging except the `+` :

```js
const array = ["1", "2", "+", "2", "1", "2"]
const result = [];
let curr = "";

for (const el of array) {
  if (el == "+") {
    result.push(curr, el);
    curr = "";
  } else {
    curr += el;
  }
}

result.push(curr);
console.log(result)
```